# Many to Many Relationship between Fact and Dimension with Parent-Child Hierarchy

Tags: many-to-many, ssas, olap

I have the following Business Scenario. I have a Fact Table with some facts. There is also a Dimension Category that has a parent-child hierarchy. There are many different hierarchies packed in one Category dimension. I mean there are a lot different types of categorization. There are also a many-to-many relationship between Fact and Category Dimension. The facts can be bound to more then one category at the time. 
I have now smth about 200 hierarchies, maybe a little bit more, but I do not expect to get more then 100k-200k rows in dimension table.

I have added Category Dimension two times to the cube in order to be able to have different hierarchies on columns and on rows. My problem is, that I do see the values ob the crosses between the different hierarchies. 
If I filter one hierarchy on rows and another one on columns, I get nothing

I think my question somehow relates to the multiple choices example from many-to-many revolution, but I have not found the sample for it.

I am using SSAS 2012 Multidimensional.

I am also interested if it is possible to smth like that in Tabular :))

Here is the Database schema

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cat](
    [cat_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [parent_cat_id] [int] NULL,
    [name] nchar NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_cat] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([cat_id] ASC)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fact](
    [fact_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] nchar NULL,
    [value] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Fact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([fact_id] ASC)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[fact_cat](
    [fact_id] [int] NULL,
    [cat_id] [int] NULL,
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_fact_cat] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[fact_cat]  ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_fact_cat_cat] FOREIGN KEY([cat_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[cat] ([cat_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[fact_cat]  ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_fact_cat_fact] FOREIGN KEY([fact_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Fact] ([fact_id])
GO

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by coping the [dbo].[fact_cat] table inside the cube. In order to do this the appropriate named query has to be added.  I have named this virtual copy table fact_cat2. Afterwards I have created a mesure for it. 
I have implemented all this based on the Survey Example from Many To Many revolution 
http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many2many/